# select body but not modal to apply blurry effect for modal backdrop

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap modal. It doesn't really matter what modal I use, the idea is apply blur filter (although it only supported in webkit).

```
    $myModal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

        $(body).addClass('modalBlur'); 
)
```

css

```
.modalBlur{
-webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(50%);
}
```

I wrote this but it apply the blurry effect to the modal itself but not the body. another concern is is there any way of doing this? apply to body will hit hard on the performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handling the `show` event instead. Also, you may want to apply the `modalBlur` to a container rather the entire body as this will make the modal blurry too.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
   $('.container').addClass('blur');
})
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/91532